# Broadcast Receiver Device Boot without Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, boot

I know there is a ton of example of this through here at Stackoverflow and even other tutorial media and yes I perfectly implemented this before but with atleast 1 `Activity`. My problem is I am building an app which only consist of `Services` that will trigger at device boot and the app does not receive any boot event in `BroadcastReceiver`

As usual I have this at `AndroidManifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name=".receiver.BootAppReceiver">
     <intent-filter android:priority="999">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is what's inside my `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    context?.let {
        startAlarmManager(it)
    }

    Log.d("BootAppReceiver", "onReceive, Context is $context")
}
```

I comment my only `Activity` at `AndroidManifest`

```
  <!--<activity android:name=".MainActivity">-->
       <!--<intent-filter>-->
         <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>-->

         <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>-->
      <!--</intent-filter>-->
  <!--</activity>-->
```

Any help and/or idea will be appreciated. Thanks

PS. It works if I uncomment the `Activity` but again this is not what I am achieving so my target is no UI/Activity at all, just `Services`.

Comment: You can't do that, since 3.1, I believe it was. Not unless there's some other app that's going to explicitly start one of your app's components. Until that happens – either by that other app, or by the explicit `Intent` that would be used to launch your `Activity` – your app will be in the _stopped_ state, and that boot Receiver won't work.

Comment: So are you saying, that instead that I implemented the boot receiver on this app, I should implement it on the other app (which will then call the service)

Comment: No, I mean that your Receiver in this app won't work until one of your components is explicitly started. That's usually done by a launcher app starting your main `Activity`. If there is indeed some other app that will explicitly start one of your components, then it only needs to do that once, and your boot Receiver will start working.

Comment: Yes there is one other app, so it should explicitly call my boot receiver. Ok I will try that.

Comment: @MikeM. what I did is instead of Broadcast Receiver, I use Service and the other app called/start it at boot start. It words perfectly. Thanks